# Run install pig from ozzie hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, oozie

I  have installed oozie on my system   and I have also installed pig.  Now I want ozzie to run workflow from pig which is installed on my system not from the ozzie sharelib.  Please help, as I get the following error:

```
2015-08-19 17:15:25,724  WARN PigActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[edb-node1] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-wf] JOB[0000002-150819170943510-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000002-150819170943510-oozie-hdus-W@pig-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exception invoking main(), java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
2015-08-19 17:15:25,728  WARN PigActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[edb-node1] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-wf] JOB[0000002-150819170943510-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000002-150819170943510-oozie-hdus-W@pig-node] Launcher exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Please format your stacktracke

Answer (score 1):

You've got error messages that show clearly that you have an incomplete CLASSPATH.

That's because the **`pig`** command line does a lot of things, among which setting up silently the appropriate Pig JARs in the CLASSPATH, before invoking the `PigMain` Java class. But Oozie calls the Java class directly; the CLASSPATH issues are supposed to be handled either...

- by the Pig ShareLib, when active
- or by you, as a knowledgeable Java developer -- after all, it's your
  choice not to use the default way to run Pig, so you know what you
  are doing, right?

Before asking your question, did you try a search on StackOverflow (and/or Google) with the following keywords? The results could prove useful.

> oozie pig custom classpath

Comment: How can I tell oozie to used pig which i had install on my System

For example i have install ozzie with pig version 1.12 and In my system i have install pig 1.14 version (version pig 1.14 ) is available on command line

Now what i want If I run workflow then ozzie will call Pig version 1.14 which is install on my system)

let me what have change in my oozie configuration

Comment: What about creating another Oozie ShareLib with the new JARs, called e.g. "Pig14", then explicitly invoking that ShareLib in the Oozie Action (therees a `<property>` for that) ?

Answer (score 0):

In the above case have you checked if you are able to access Pig CLI {grunt shell} or are you able to running Pig Script manually, without Using Oozie.

The Case what happend is Pig Jar was not accessable while You are trying to use  via Oozie,  the Best Case to avoide such issue is to use Oozie - -ShareLib , but as You mention you dnt want the same to work using sharedlib, then use some alternate case like:

1. Update Pig Home Path in Hadoop ClassPath. These will help MR to fetch the List of Jars in HDFS Temp Location every time Oozie Submit Request to MR.
2. Update Pig Home in BashProfile {if Pig shows error while accessing GRANT Shell with Command not Found}.

Hope these will help some.

Comment: How can I tell oozie to used pig which i had install on my System

For example i have install ozzie with pig version 1.12 and In my system i have install pig 1.14 version (version pig 1.14 ) is available on command line

Now what i want If I run workflow then ozzie will call Pig version 1.14 which is install on my system)

let me what have change in my oozie configuration